# vba code for updating the pivot table filter based on a column range 1 by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code for pivot table filter and done with researching about it.
i have a column naming "Name"(H) and have a pivot table filtered on "Name". I am trying to write vba code for the same where the code is to update the filter 1 by 1 based on the  cell values of the column "Name"(H). I could achieve in writing the code which assigns the pivot filter to single cell but not to the entire range of name 1 by 1.

But the final goal is:
Change the pivot filter value 1 by 1 based on the "Name"(H) column and have a table which changes according to the pivot value filter and paste these tables into Powerpoint. 1 slide for each pivot filter value. for example:
Name column has :x,y,z
put these values 1 by 1 inside the pivot value filter and insert the tables into the powerpoint.1st x to be assigned to the pivot value filter,the table changes accrodingly for x and put this table into Powerpoint as slide and same for y and so on.
It would be great help in solving this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO please take the [tour] and [ask]. Also provide some [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the same which assigns only a single cell value to the pivot table filter"
Sub final()

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim pvtfield As PivotField

Set PT = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set pvtfield = PT.PivotFields("Name")
pvtfield.CurrentPage = CStr(Range("H2").Value)

Set PT = Nothing
```

End Sub